# Accessing specific URL throws 404 error for website hosted on GoDaddy

Tags: node.js, angular, hosting, web-hosting, godaddy-api

I have a angular7/mysql/node.js website hosted on GoDaddy and I'm facing following issue.

When I access website using base URL like [www.abcdef.com](http://www.abcdef.com), it opens home page and then using links provided on home page to go to other pages like About Us, Contact Us, etc. I can access those pages.
But if I try to access a page using specific URL like [www.abcdef.com/aboutus](http://www.abcdef.com/aboutus), website throws an 404 error and I'm redirected to error page.

I'm new to hosting and stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When you navigate to the about us page, what do you get displayed in as URL in your browser? And when you run the project locally you can go to the specific URL directly without errors?

Comment: @CharlieV Yes, locally im able to to do that without errors and URL in my browser is what it should be, but it doesnt work

Comment: Do you build in a different way for localhost deployment vs GoDaddy deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured your server to redirect requests to missing files to index.html?

See https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration. I'm not familiar with GoDaddy hosting, but I'm guessing you should add the .htaccess file (create/edit the .htaccess file in the root folder):

```
  RewriteEngine On 
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR] 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
  RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
 
  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html 
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: This was the issue...i forgot to add the rule...thx man